# function that targets DOM to display game results not responding despite calling function and there are no console errors either

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why the function endResult() does not work when either winning or losing a game of hangman.

I have called the function at the bottom of the code and there are no errors in the console.

But when the game finishes (either guessing the word completely within 5 guesses or running out of guesses), there is no action taken from this function.

This is my first intermediate challenge and I still clearly have a lot to learn but any help would be extremely welcome.

Thanks

```
//global variables.

//counter to display how many tries you have left at guessing correct characters.
var triesLeft = 5;

//dom targets.
var guessCount = document.querySelector("#guesses, p"); //display how many tries you have left in dom target.
var resetButton = document.querySelector(".button"); // reset buton
var displayWord = document.getElementById("puzzle") //dom target to show random word

//arrays
var words = ["hello world", "happy birthday", "you got talent", "china town", "leap frog",
  "true lies", "artificial inteligence", "knoledge is power", "monday blues", "autonomous vehicles"];
var wrongGuess = [];

//pick a word randomly.
var randomiseWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
//hide all characters within [a-z] and replace with *.
var randomiseWordHide = randomiseWord.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '*');


function displayGame() {
//insert each character of the random word into a span tag hidden as *.
  for (var i = 0; i < randomiseWord.length; i++) {
    var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
    displayWord.appendChild(spanTag);
    spanTag.textContent = randomiseWordHide[i];
  }
};


function makeAGuess(event) {
//if correct guess, reveal characters,
  for (var j = 0; j < randomiseWord.length; j++) {
    if (randomiseWord[j] === event.key) {
      document.querySelectorAll("span")[j].textContent = event.key;
//else reduce tries left by 1.
    } else if (!randomiseWord.includes(event.key)) {
      guessCount.textContent = "Guesses Left:" + " " + (triesLeft - wrongGuess.length);
    }
  }
  //if incorrect guess, push to array to keep count. keep this condition out of the loop.
    if (!randomiseWord.includes(event.key)) {
      wrongGuess.push(event.key);
    }
};


function endResult() {
//if word is guessed correctly before running out of guesses.
  for (var k=0; k<randomiseWord; k++) {
    if (triesLeft >0 && !document.querySelectorAll("span")[j].includes("*")) {
      document.querySelector("#guesses, p").textContent = "Well done, you guessed the word with" + triesLeft + "  tries left.";
//if all guesses are used and word not complete.
    } else if (triesLeft === 0) {
      document.querySelector("#guesses, p").textContent = "Nice try, the word was" + '"' + randomiseWord + '".';
  }
};


//create a reload button that displays a new random word when clicked.
function reloadScreen() {
  reload = location.reload();
}


//listener for keydown
document.addEventListener("keydown", makeAGuess); // can also pass function from here.
//listener for reload button.
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reloadScreen, false);

//call functions.
  displayGame();
  endResult();
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] that shows the actual behavior.

Comment: You have a typo in selector ... `querySelector("#guesses, p")`. Since no html was provided it's not clear what that should be doing

Comment: Also, the function 'displayGame()' has a trailing ; after the ending }.

Comment: charlietfl... i have checked this in the console and it correctly displays the DOM target it supposed to, also i can change the value with textContent to make sure it is correct.

Comment: CharlesEF, all my functions have a semicolon  after the closing curly bracket. is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @charlietfl Where is the typo? a comma separated list is valid - even for `querySelector`...

Comment: The function `endResult()` isn't called when the guess was correct or if there are no tries left. You just call the function once at script load...

Comment: @biberman, Hi, thanks this sounds like a simple problem solved, however i don't know how to change the syntax accordingly to suit your response, sorry to a pain but can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function endResult() isn't called when the guess was correct or if there are no tries left. You just call the function once at script load. Therefor you should call it in the function `makeAGuess()`:

```js
function makeAGuess(event) {
//if correct guess, reveal characters,
  for (var j = 0; j < randomiseWord.length; j++) {
    if (randomiseWord[j] === event.key) {
      document.querySelectorAll("span")[j].textContent = event.key;
//else reduce tries left by 1.
    } else if (!randomiseWord.includes(event.key)) {
      guessCount.textContent = "Guesses Left:" + " " + (triesLeft - wrongGuess.length);
    }
  }
  //if incorrect guess, push to array to keep count. keep this condition out of the loop.
    if (!randomiseWord.includes(event.key)) {
      wrongGuess.push(event.key);
    }
  endResult();
};
```

Furthermore there are two issues in `endResult()`:

- `triesLeft` never gets updated an remains `5` -> use `wrongGuess.length` instead
- `!document.querySelectorAll("span")[j].includes("*")` isn't valid - you have to loop over all span tags and check the condition separately:

```js
function endResult() {
    //if word is guessed correctly before running out of guesses.
    const letters = document.querySelectorAll("span");
    let solved = false;
    
    for (let m = 0; m < letters.length; m++) {
        if (letters[m].textContent == "*") {
            solved = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            solved = true;
        }
    }
    
    if (wrongGuess.length < 5 && solved) {
      document.querySelector("#guesses, p").textContent = "Well done, you guessed the word with" + (triesLeft - wrongGuess.length) + "  tries left.";
    //if all guesses are used and word not complete.
    } else if (wrongGuess.length >= 5) {
      document.querySelector("#guesses, p").textContent = "Nice try, the word was" + '"' + randomiseWord + '".';
    }
};
```

**Working example:**

```js
//global variables.

//counter to display how many tries you have left at guessing correct characters.
var triesLeft = 5;

//dom targets.
var guessCount = document.querySelector("#guesses, p"); //display how many tries you have left in dom target.
var resetButton = document.querySelector(".button"); // reset buton
var displayWord = document.getElementById("puzzle") //dom target to show random word

//arrays
var words = ["hello world", "happy birthday", "you got talent", "china town", "leap frog",
  "true lies", "artificial inteligence", "knoledge is power", "monday blues", "autonomous vehicles"
];
var wrongGuess = [];

//pick a word randomly.
var randomiseWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
//hide all characters within [a-z] and replace with *.
var randomiseWordHide = randomiseWord.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '*');

function displayGame() {
  //insert each character of the random word into a span tag hidden as *.
  for (var i = 0; i < randomiseWord.length; i++) {
    var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
    displayWord.appendChild(spanTag);
    spanTag.textContent = randomiseWordHide[i];
  }
};

function makeAGuess(event) {
  //if correct guess, reveal characters,
  for (var j = 0; j < randomiseWord.length; j++) {
    if (randomiseWord[j] === event.key) {
      document.querySelectorAll("span")[j].textContent = event.key;
      //else reduce tries left by 1.
    } else if (!randomiseWord.includes(event.key)) {
      guessCount.textContent = "Guesses Left:" + " " + (triesLeft - wrongGuess.length - 1);
    }
  }
  //if incorrect guess, push to array to keep count. keep this condition out of the loop.
  if (!randomiseWord.includes(event.key)) {
    wrongGuess.push(event.key);
  }
  endResult();
};

function endResult() {
  //if word is guessed correctly before running out of guesses.
  const letters = document.querySelectorAll("span");
  let solved = false;

  for (let m = 0; m < letters.length; m++) {
    if (letters[m].textContent == "*") {
      solved = false;
      break;
    } else {
      solved = true;
    }
  }

  if (wrongGuess.length < 5 && solved) {
    document.querySelector("#guesses, p").textContent = "Well done, you guessed the word with" + (triesLeft - wrongGuess.length) + "  tries left.";
    //if all guesses are used and word not complete.
  } else if (wrongGuess.length >= 5) {
    document.querySelector("#guesses, p").textContent = "Nice try, the word was" + '"' + randomiseWord + '".';
  }
};

//create a reload button that displays a new random word when clicked.
function reloadScreen() {
  reload = location.reload();
}

//listener for keydown
document.addEventListener("keydown", makeAGuess);
//listener for reload button.
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reloadScreen, false);

//call functions.
displayGame();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background: #2B292E;
  color: #fafafa;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #534f59;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
  margin: 0 .1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 2.4rem;
}

p {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: .8rem;
}

.puzzle {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
}

.button {
  background: #7044a0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #603a88;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: .8rem;
  transition: background .3s ease, color .3s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #5F3A87;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="puzzle" class="puzzle"></div>

  <p id="guesses"></p>

  <button id="reset" class="button">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This has just gave me a "doh!" moment, i understand know perfectly. thanks very much for a prompt answer, you got my vote!.

Comment: i had to untick "accept answer" as unfortunately despite calling endResult()  at script load, there is still no difference. would you have any other suggestions? thanks for a very useful reply though!

Comment: I would like to test it but i need the html for that. Do have a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Ok can you try this link, https://codepen.io/nezza2005/pen/LYyqjWg

Comment: I got a solution! Give me some time to edit my answer...

Comment: Done - test it!

Comment: Thanks i am just absorbing this information now so it soaks in, i will get back shortly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235895/discussion-between-nezza1-and-biberman).